# Electric Flux of A Point Charge Derivation

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, field-theory, mathematics

I am trying to understand the derivation of Gauss's Law and came across this line describing the electric flux through a small area of a sphere from a point charge: [Source](http://www.ux1.eiu.edu/~cfadd/1360/24Gauss/Gauss.html) $$ E\cdot\Delta A_i = E_n\Delta A_i = E\Delta A_i$$

Where:

- E = electric field
- A = area on the imaginary sphere of electric fields surrounding a
  point charge.

Why is the dot product used in this case? I understand that the dot product is the projection of the electric field onto the area. The electric field lines radiate perpendicularly from the charged centre of the sphere and so does the direction of the area vector (if you define it that way).  <strike>So wouldn't $ E\cdot\Delta A_i =0$? If it is not the dot product that should be here, what should be used instead?</strike>

Thank you

Comment: What direction can be the vector for an area?

Comment: @jaromrax Oh! An area can't have a vector direction as it is a scalar! Though, why was the dot product written in that line instead of a multiply sign?

Comment: Area can be a vector.

Comment: @KarthikV. Thank you, you are right. There is such a thing as an area vector. (http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/iar1/teaching/Vector_Areas_Tutorial.pdf) [Sorry I can't seem to make it a link]

Comment: @jaromrax: The direction for an area vector is the normal to the area, though it can point inwards or outwards from the sphere depending on the traversal direction you define. That explains why E⋅ΔAi = EΔAi, not 0. It is a simplification of having to write the flux as the product of field strength, area and cosine of angle between electric field and area. I will update this in my question.

Comment: @user314901 you  are welcome :)

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/imgele/eflux.png That picture might help!

Answer (score 0):

Because only the *perpendicular* component of the electric field contributes to the flux through an area. To simplify notation we define an infinitesimal 'area vector' as
$$
d\mathbf A \equiv \mathbf n \, dA
$$
where $\mathbf n$ is the local normal vector of the surface. So you can either write Gauss' law as
$$
\oint_S \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{A} = \oint_S (\mathbf{E\cdot n}) \, dA =  Q/\epsilon_0.
$$